# Get filtered results in a dataframe by using a particular column in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas data frame with multiple columns- something like this

```
                    targetName  ... atRiskCommonPurchased
0                   Twitter, Inc.  ...             NaN
1                   Forbes Media  ...              NaN
2                   Adobe  ...                     NaN
3                   Virgin Airlines  ...           NaN
4                   H&M  ...                       NaN
[5 rows x 51 columns]
```

And I have also have a column in the same data frame which is of dates:

```
df['dealAnnouncementDate'].dtype
dtype('O')
print(df['dealAnnouncementDate'])
0      2021-08-30
1      2021-08-26
2      2021-08-25
3      2021-08-23
4      2021-08-18
```

using `df.between()` I can easily filter the dataframe using the date column and get the result. something like: `df[df['dealAnnouncementDate'].between('7/27/2021', '8/27/2021')]`

But, I would be runnning the python script on every 7th day(take for instance Monday), How do I ensure that using `dealAnnouncementDate` column I get filtered results for 7 days? Please help me to understand how can it be done! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need filter between some dates, e.g. now and next 7 days use:

```
df['dealAnnouncementDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dealAnnouncementDate'])

now = pd.to_datetime('now').normalize()
print (now)
2021-08-31 00:00:00

df[df['dealAnnouncementDate'].between(now, now + pd.Timedelta('7days'))]
```

For previous 7 days:

```
df[df['dealAnnouncementDate'].between(now - pd.Timedelta('7days'), now )]
```